# In-place modification of gzip files

Tags: python, gzip, in-place

I need to modify a gzipped tab-delimited file. I can read from input and write modified reads to an output file as:

```py
output = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w", delete=False)
with gzip.open(input, "rb") as in_file,\
     gzip.open(output, "wb") as out_file:
    for l in in_file:
        split_line = l.split("\t")
        if split_line[0] == "hello":
            split_line[0] = "hi"
        out_file.write("\t".join(split_line))
```

The gzipped files I work with are in 100s of GB scale, hence rewriting the entire file to a different file only for modifying a subset is not ideal. Therefore, I am interested in a solution that modifies the file **in-place** (i.e., modifying the original file as you traverse through it).

Comment: The gzip compression format doesn't allow for in-place modification.

Comment: Indeed, and I was hoping if someone knows any tricks for in-place or even close to in-place modification.

Comment: It's really impossible. It's a stream compression algorithm, so if you change something in the file, everything after it is affected.

Comment: It may be time for you to consider a different format for your data..  SQLite, perhaps, or maybe even one of the SQL servers.

Comment: Sure, though that has a more significant impact/footprint on the project that needs to be tabled for later ;-)

Comment: I mean, if you intentionally structure your gzip file to have the compression table reset every so often, and then have padding that can be used if the new content is larger than the old content, it's _theoretically_ possible to implement, but theoretically possible != practical.

Comment: (Mind, some newer filesystems let you expand files in the middle at block boundaries, so if you combine a periodic compression-table reset with that functionality you can add new data in the middle of the file even when it's larger, but you still need to deal with making everything align properly _after_ the inserted blocks... and this is all contingent on a sufficietly-modern filesystem).

Comment: ...which is all to say, rewriting to use sqlite is probably less work, especially if you don't control system administration of the machines this code is going to run on.

Comment: BTW, if you want to learn more about what I'm talking about re: "resetting the compression table" -- search for "rsyncable gzip".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normal gzip files, certainly not. Your only option would be read the gzip file up to where you want the modification, make the modification, and recompress the rest. Some attention is required where you make the cut, to remove the deflate block that includes the cut, and recompress from there, appending the remaining deflate blocks on the correct bit position.

You could, in theory, prepare a large gzip file so that such modifications could be done in place. You would need to break up the gzip file into independent blocks, where the history at the start of each block is discarded. (pigz does this with the `--independent` option.) You would also need to insert several empty blocks or other filler space at the end of each independent block to allow for variations in the length of the independent block so that the modified result can fit back into the exact same number of bytes. There are five-byte and two-byte empty blocks you can insert, that in combination should be able to accommodate any small number of byte count difference, if you have enough of them.

You would need a separate index of the locations of these independent blocks, otherwise you would be spending time searching for them, again making the time dependent on the length of the file.

In order to not significantly impact the overall compression ratio of the gzip file, you would want the independent blocks to be on the order of 128K bytes uncompressed or larger. Any modification would require recompression of an entire independent block.

You would also need to update the CRC and length at the end of the gzip file. I think that there's a way to update the CRC without recomputing it for the whole file, but I'd have to think about it. It is certainly possible if the length of the file doesn't change, but if you are inserting or deleting bytes, it gets trickier.

This would all be a large amount of work to try to put a square gzip peg into a round random modification hole. It suggests that you are simply using the wrong format for the application. Find a different format for what you want to do.