# How to update lines in a compressed file

Tags: python, gzip, compressed-files

I have a large compressed `.gz` file (gigabyte level) that contains one large `.txt` file. Currently, I can add new lines to the end of the file without any problem. But I wonder if there's any way to **update** or **modify** lines as we iterate through the file? In my case, I have tab-separated lines where each tab-separated item is a column in my dataset. I need to add one more column to this data. One way is to create a new file, read the `.gz` file lines one by one, update them, and write them to the new file. However, this is not ideal since 1) the file is huge, and writing will take time, and 2) I may need to do this multiple times and more frequently.

Comment: In general, this is not possible.  But see [In-place modification of gzip files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69197360/in-place-modification-of-gzip-files) for some suggestions.

Comment: Nope. If you need to add a column to every line, the only way is to decompress, modify, and recompress the whole thing.